# Meaning of "as soon"

Tags: meaning

Can "as soon" be used by itself in a sentence? For example:

> Finish your work and leave as soon.

Is this a complete sentence?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would be a complete sentence. A better use of 'as soon' would be : *Finish your work and leave as soon **as it's done***.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is unclear, which is perhaps why it has attracted a down vote. It seems perhaps that it might be better posted on SE English Language Learners, where someone might help sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use "as soon" you need to use "as soon as." "Finish your work and leave as soon" is not a complete sentence.

Here is the correct way to say it:

> You can leave as soon as you finish your work.
>
> As soon as you finish your work, you can leave.

---

Let me explain how to use "as soon as."

[Merriam-Webster defines "as soon as" like this:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as%20soon%20as)

> Immediately at or shortly after the time that

[The Collins Dictionary definition:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-soon-as)

> If you say that something happens as soon as something else happens,
>   you mean that it happens immediately after the other thing.

There must always be some action after "as soon as."

A as soon as B. --> You do A immediately after B happens.

> I changed my shirt *as soon as* I got home.

Meaning: You got home (B).  Then, you immediately changed your shirt (A).

Here are some more examples.

> Please reply to my email *as soon as* you wake up.
>
> I will draw your picture *as soon as* I buy some pencils.
>
> *As soon as* he walked in the door, the class started laughing. (B as soon as A)

[It might be a little difficult to understand, but here is a website talking about how to use "as soon as."](http://speakspeak.com/resources/english-grammar-rules/conjunctions/as-soon-as)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as is a **conjunction**. You use as soon as to say that something will happen immediately after something else has happened.

Comment: This is a verbatim quote; it needs attributing to avoid possible infringement of copyright.